# Sitecore: Error when indexing Treelist field?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-lucene

I have an index in Sitecore.   One of the fields of the template being indexed is a treelist field called "tags".   When I inspect the index using Luke, I see the field and it had values.

1.) The values in the tags index is the ID of the selected treelist item -- I need it to be the display name.

2.) Now my Crawling logs are filled with:

> WARN  You have specified both IncludeTemplates and ExcludeTemplates.
>   This logic is not supported. Exclude templates will be ignored.

This is what I have for my indexing configuration, but evidently I have something incorrect:

```xml
<index id="knowledge_center_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration">
        <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <generalTemplatePage>{AD63DB1D-A3A5-4D16-9F19-7D878BBE2568}</generalTemplatePage>
            <newsPage>{85901309-D07C-447B-97DA-EA6F1581832C}</newsPage>
            <inTheNewsPage>{C49A9219-231D-42C6-AED2-9115CC241247}</inTheNewsPage>
        </include>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
        <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                <fieldType fieldName="tags" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
            </fieldNames>
        </fieldMap>
    </configuration>
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
    </strategies>
    <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </policies>
    </commitPolicyExecutor>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Sites/My Site/Knowledge Center</Root>
        </crawler>
    </locations>
</index>
```

---

UPDATE: @Marek Musielak -- For #1, I followed the link you pointed to in your answer and am getting this kind of error over and over in my Crawling.logs:

> 6272 12:49:18 ERROR Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField:
>   potential for indexable:
>   sitecore://master/{2D06E798-6BFE-4089-A610-5C341BF28B09}?lang=en&ver=3
>   Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
>   mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred,
>   IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportingQueryBase..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase
>   reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Reporting.TestPotentialQuery..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase
>   reportProvider)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestPotentialMetricBase.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable
>   indexable)    at
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFields()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
>   mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[]
>   parameters)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)    at
>   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath,
>   String[] parameters, Boolean assert)    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Reports.StimulsoftIntegration.BuiltInFunctionsReportDataSource..ctor()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException Message: Cannot use
>   DataAdapterProvider as Analytics is disabled. Source:
>   Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB    at
>   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.MongoDb.MongoDbDataAdapterProvider..ctor(Func`2
>   driverFactory)

Why does it care if Analytics is disabled?

---

UPDATE 2: @Rogier

I needed to move the fieldMap into the defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration:

```
<defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
        <field patch:before="field[0]" fieldName="tags" storageType="YES" indexType="UNTOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
    </fieldNames>
</fieldMap>
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
    <field patch:before="field[0]" fieldName="tags">MyNamespace.Search.ComputedFields, MyNamespace.Search</field>
</fields>
```

The main index patch ended up looking like:

```
<index id="knowledge_center_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
    <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration">
        <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <generalTemplatePage>{AD63DB1D-A3A5-4D16-9F19-7D878BBE2568}</generalTemplatePage>
            <newsPage>{85901309-D07C-447B-97DA-EA6F1581832C}</newsPage>
            <inTheNewsPage>{C49A9219-231D-42C6-AED2-9115CC241247}</inTheNewsPage>
        </include>
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
    </configuration>
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild" />
    </strategies>
    <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </policies>
    </commitPolicyExecutor>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Sites/My Site/Knowledge Center</Root>
        </crawler>
    </locations>
```

I hope this is helpful...

Comment: Can you look in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config and see if "<exclude hint=........" is set there. You can also look in /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx and look for it there.

Comment: Did you ever fix the problem `Cannot use DataAdapterProvider as Analytics is disabled` listed in your update? We've got the same one. My Google-Fu is failing me, though: Can't find any possible causes online.

Comment: @RogiervanhetSchip I added another update that will hopefully help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ad 1):

By default Sitecore indexes ids of the chosen items. The reason for that is simple: lets assume for a second that Sitecore stores names of the tags. Imagine that you've chosen `TagA` and `TagB` for `MyArticle` item. Sitecore indexes your `MyArticle` item, and saves `TagA` and `TagB` values in the index. Now you renamed `TagA` to `Other TagA`. Sitecore doesn't re-crawl your `MyArticle` cause it hasn't changed (only tag item changed). So your `MyArticle` item has incorrect values in index - it's still `TagA` there.

Sure, if you know that you'll **NEVER** change name (or display name) of any of your tags, you can easily create a computed field, which will keep item display names. There is example how you can do this in this blog post: [Computed index field for MultiList type field](https://sitecorenotes.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/sc7-computed-index-field/)

Ad 2):

Just go to the `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page and check if there is any place with `ExcludeTemplate` defined. Then trace that entry in your `App_Config\Include` folder and voila.

Comment: 2.) I found two references to ExcludeTemplate in showconfig.   Both appear to be built-in... one in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Cloud.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config and one in Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration.config

If I remove these is it going to create issues?